# How to get current state (Is Checked or Unchecked) of Angular Material Multiselect

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material2

I am using MatSelect with multiple selections of items. I want the state of a current item for ex. The currently clicked item is checked or unchecked. On the basis of the state, I will have to open a dialogue box.

Answer (score 2):

If only they had some documentation ...

[**... Oh Wait !**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect)

> `selected: MatOption | MatOption[]`                                   The currently selected option.

### EDIT

In the HTML

```
<mat-select #select (change)="x()" ...>
  <option *ngFor="let x of y" ...></option>
</mat-select>
```

In the TS

```
@ViewChild('select') select: MatSelect;

x() {
  console.log(this.select.selected);
}
```

Now you have the selected values (and hence, the unselected values)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more or any code reference? I just want to get whether a clicked item of the dropdown is clicked for check or click for uncheck an item

Comment: It's quite complicated that means by above code it gives selected value and after that value have to compare unselected value any other option? I am expecting a 1-2 line of code which will do a trick for me. Currently what happens if I select then event get called if I deselect then also event gets called

Comment: Yeah well that's kind of the purpose if you want to get the selected items. If you un select an item, both selected and unselected arrays change, so you need to check for changes.

Comment: Only that is the problem here is my code --> 
<mat-select  formControlName="tagList" id="tagList" placeholder="Select Tag" name="tagList" multiple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let tag of tagList" [value]="tag" 
(click)="isSelectedTagIsCallback(tag, $event)">
{{tag.name}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
So on each check / Uncheck isSelectedTagIsCallback() Method and for every event its mandatory to check

Comment: Then your remove the code from your option ... I shouldn't have to tell you that, you're supposed to work on your side too you know.

Comment: Sorry..? Didn't get you!

Comment: Remove the output you have in your option tag.

Answer (score 1):

On the mat-option, you can add a click event and log it to track:

```
<mat-option value="abc" (click)="onOptionClick($event)">abc</mat-option>
```

And in the .ts component:

```
onOptionClick(event){
console.log(event.target.selected);
}
```

Comment: There is no such property name selected in the target object. Any other flag to check its current state?

Answer (score 1):

Easist method just pass the $event.target.selected to a method in .ts and you can open a dialogue box based on the state.

in .html

```
<mat-option value="val" (click)="onClick($event.target.selected)">val</mat-option>
```

in .ts file

```
onOClick(isSelected){
   if(isSelected){
    //selected state
   }else{
   //not selected state
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried with above one but the target.selected property is undefined

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 6 this is what worked for me (tested only in Safari).

HTML

```
<input (change)="yourFunction($event)" type="checkbox" name="your-name">
```

TS

```
private yourFunction(event)
{
   console.log(event.target.checked);
}
```